# How to get teamsId from Microsoft.Bot.Schema.Teams.MessagingExtensionAction?

Tags: teams-toolkit

I need help with my message extension. I want to retrieve teamsId, channelId, and messageId in my message extension and call my web api for doing some processing. Currently channelId and messageId is available, that is retrieved from  MessageExtensionAction.MessageActionsPayload (ChannelData or LinkToMessage and Id), how to get teamsId? Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from ChannelData of the IInvokeActivity like this:

```
string teamsId = turnContext.Activity.TeamsGetTeamInfo()?.AadGroupId;
```

**however, AadGroupId is always null**.
Currently enumerating the joined teams and channels and detect the team that includes the current channelId. I don't find a simple solution.